# How to install a module for python 2.6 on CentOS?

Tags: python, centos, yum, pypdf

After I install python 2.6 on CentOS by:

```
 wget http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
 sudo rpm -ivh epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
 yum install python26
```

Then I install `pyPdf` by:

```
 yum install pyPdf
```

However, the `pyPdf` is only available to the old python 2.4:

```
# python
Python 2.4.3 (#1, Jan  9 2013, 06:49:54) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-54)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyPdf
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.path
['', '/usr/lib/python24.zip', '/usr/lib/python2.4', '/usr/lib/python2.4/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.4/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.4/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Numeric', '/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/gtk-2.0']
```

it's not available to the newly install python 2.6:

```
# python26
Python 2.6.8 (unknown, Nov  7 2012, 14:47:34) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.path
['', '/usr/lib/python26.zip', '/usr/lib/python2.6', '/usr/lib/python2.6/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages']
>>> import pyPdf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pyPdf
```

How can I install `pyPdf` for python 2.6?

Answer (score 1):

How about creating a `virtualenv` and install `pyPdf` with `pip`

```
$ curl -O https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-X.X.tar.gz
$ tar xvfz virtualenv-X.X.tar.gz
$ cd virtualenv-X.X
$ python26 virtualenv.py myVirtualenv
$ source myVirtualenv/bin/activate
$ pip install pyPdf
```

Read more about virtualenv [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you're doing it. I have recently installed pyPdf on CentOS for Python 2.7. A simple yum worked for me.

> yum install pyPdf

pyPdf is also available for newer versions. Check [here](http://pybrary.net/pyPdf/)

### Edit:

> May be having two different versions of Python is causing this issue
>   for you. CentOS comes with default installation of v2.4. Remove all
>   the previous versions and install again.

Comment: pypdf2 is the most up to date version it is different than pypdf

Answer (score 0):

For CentOS version lower than 6, python 2.4 comes by default. For version 6 and above its python2.6 .

Now I would strictly advise not to upgrade the base Python installation i.e python2.4 in the earlier versions, as that would break lot of system level funcationalities that expect default python to be 2.4.

Your question can be solved in multiple ways :

1. yum install always does an installation for default python. If its 2.4 it will install the package for 2.4.
2. To install package for 2.6, download easy_install for 2.6 or PIP for 2.6 and then simply do easy_install {{package_name}} or pip install {{package_name}}
3. To keep your environments different, as suggested by @Dikei  install a virtual-env and then install your packages. This is method is one of the best practices for maintaining multiple python environments.

Answer (score 0):

Quick installation of **Python** !!!

Get the latest verion of Python 2.6.9

```
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.6.9/Python-2.6.9.tar.xz
```

Extract thae package

```
tar xf Python-2.6.9.tar.xz
```

Configure them

```
cd Python-2.6.9
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-unicode=ucs4 --enable-shared LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath /usr/local/lib"
```

Install them

```
make && make altinstall
```

Check Version:

```
python --version
Python 2.6.9
```

**Credits**:https://danieleriksson.net

Hope this helps !!!